Porque no puedo obtener las lista de childrens




Solo obtendo la lista de childItems cuando no tiene ningun wrapper.No entiendo que esta pasando aqui alguien por favor que me ayude

Comparte el código como texto.

El código y los mensajes de error siempre como texto, con formato. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

@ContentChildren(ChildItemComponent, { descendants: true })
Por lo que he leido para obtener los hijos que no sean decsendientes directos se debe seter a tru la propiedad descendants. Igual si alguien tiene una mejor explicacion estare muy agradecido

Por favor, estructura tu respuesta acorde a las reglas de la comunidad. Al parecer estás escribiendo una respuesta cuando podría ser un comentario en la parte superior donde se encuentra el enlace "Añade un comentario", así lograrás captar mayor atención y atraer a posibles usuarios que te puedan ayudar en tu problema y por último, agrega código y NO imágenes! Saludos!

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
